# MySQL Database Connection via SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, linux, database, shell, ssh

i have a problem with our new database. The only way to access the database is throw a SSH tunnel. But it doesn't work...

I use following commands:

```
sshpass -p <PASSWORD> ssh <USER>@<DOMAIN> -p <PORT> -L 3306:localhost:3306 -f -N
```

I think the ssh tunnel works and is established.

Now I want to connect via Shell-File the database.

```
deposit=`mysql -h localhost --port=3306 -u <DATABASEUSER> --password=<DATABASEPASSWORD> --skip-column-names -e "<MYSQLSYNTAX>"`
```

But there is always folowing error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<DATABASEUSER>'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Do you have any ideas or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your permissions are okay, it may be worth swapping `localhost` for `127.0.0.1`.

As per the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a
>   way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
>   network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs
>   attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.
>   This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port
>   number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the
>   local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of
>   127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to create a tunnel between your computer and a remote computer that's running SQL server. In your ssh command substitute 3306:localhost:3306 with the remote computer IP address. Note this should be its internal local IP address if you are not in the same local network as the remote computer. Check your SQL Database permissions, username and password as well.